# Call Oracle procedure from C# when procedure is in different schema

Tags: c#, oracle

I'm trying to call a pretty simple procedure, and if I'm in the Toad editor, it works fine:

```
BEGIN OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch('BatchName'); END;
```

This schema has permissions to execute P_CloseBatch that exists in OtherSchema.

I'm connecting in C# to the same schema, using this code:

```
try 
{ 
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleStgConnectionString))
    {
          connection.Open();
          OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
          command.Connection = connection;
          command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          command.CommandText = "BEGIN OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch('BatchName'); END;";
          command.ExecuteNonQuery();
          connection.Close();
     }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     Log.Info(e.Message);
}
```

And when I get to the command.ExecuteNonQuery, it gives me a long error:

> {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 83:\nPLS-00103: Encountered the symbol \")\" when expecting one of the following:\n\n   ( - + case mod new not null \n    \n   continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev\n   sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval\n   date \n     pipe\n   \n

All my searching makes it look like that CommandText is appropriate, but it's not.  All I can think of is that it's in a different schema.  Is that the problem, or is there something else I don't see?

If instead of the CommandText value above, I have the following instead:

```
command.CommandText = "OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch('BatchName')";
```

Then the error I get is:

> - $exception  {"ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPLS-00801: internal error [22503]\nORA-06550: line 1, column 7:\nPL/SQL: Statement ignored"}    Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException

I can split it up so the command text is separate, and the batch name is added as a parameter:

```
 connection.Open();
 OracleCommand command = new OracleCommand();
 command.Connection = connection;
 command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
 command.CommandText = "OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch(:batchname)";
 String parameterBatchName = "BatchName";
 command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(":batchname", parameterBatchName ));
 command.ExecuteNonQuery();
 connection.Close();
```

And that error is "+        $exception  {"ORA-01008: not all variables bound"}  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException
"

That seems like a very simple error.  I'm using the same syntax as queries that do work, but they are updates instead of calls to a procedure.

Comment: When you specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, `CommandText` should be the name of the procedure, not a PL/SQL script. Then add the `"BatchName"` value as a parameter.

Comment: @madreflection - that gives an error too, but a different one.

Comment: That's because you're specifying more than the name.

Comment: @madreflection - ok, I'll go try adding the parameter.  Hang on.  (Because I'd tried that and also got an error, but perhaps it was syntactical, and trying again will work.)

Comment: @madreflection - still no go.  And yet, it seems like a simple error.

Comment: When you run `"BEGIN OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch('BatchName'); END;"` then CommandType has to be `CommandType.Text`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thank you, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify `CommandType.StoredProcedure`, the `CommandText` should be the name of the procedure, not a PL/SQL script.  The parameter is passed in the `Parameters` collection.

```cs
using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(oracleStgConnectionString))
using (OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    connection.Open();

    command.BindByName = true;
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.CommandText = "OtherSchema.P_CloseBatch";

    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter()
    {
        ParameterName = "batchname",
        OracleDbType = OracleDbType.NVarchar2
        Value = parameterBatchName
    });

    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Call to connection.Close removed as the "using" block already does that.
}
```

I've thrown in a few other changes:

- Created `command` using `connection.CreateCommand` because it assigns the connection before returning the object.
- A `using` block on `command` because it's also disposable.
- Setting `BindByName` so the parameter name I specify actually means something.

Comment: And I finally see what you meant by me using more than the name.  It works!  Thank you so much.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Were you able to integrate the other changes/suggestions I made?

Comment: Yes - I used them all.  I had to make one minor change because of how I obfuscated my code.   You helped a lot, and I'm testing my last section now, with that code in 5 places (for 5 different batches).

Comment: You can also use shorter form `command.Parameters.Add("batchname", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = parameterBatchName;`

Comment: True, you can, but *I advise against it*. I've seen questions on SO where the wrong overload is mistakenly used, such as using the wrong Db Type enum and it ends up being the `value` parameter. This way prevents any of those mistakes. Plus, you don't have to think about parameter order for the overload you want. Regardless of which properties you need to set, like including the direction; this way makes it entirely uniform.